# Test for undefined fact in puppet

Tags: puppet

With puppet 5.3.3. in my local environment.

**$facts['ec2_metadata']['instance-id']** doesn't exits.

I have tried this...

```
$instance_id = pick($facts['ec2_metadata']['instance-id'], $facts['ipaddress'])
```

And this...

```
  if defined($facts['ec2_metadata']['instance-id']) {
    $instance_id = $facts['ec2_metadata']['instance-id']
  } else {
    $instance_id = $facts['ipaddress']
  }
```

And this ...

```
  if getvar($facts['ec2_metadata']['instance-id']) {

    $instance_id = $facts['ec2_metadata']['instance-id']
  } else {

    $instance_id = $facts['ipaddress']
  }
```

And this ...

```
  if $facts['ec2_metadata']['instance-id'] != undef {

    $instance_id = $facts['ec2_metadata']['instance-id']
  } else {

    $instance_id = $facts['ipaddress']
  }
```

As expected, I always get ...

```
==> default: Error: Evaluation Error: Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value. at ...
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Even this launch the error.

```
notify{$facts['ec2_metadata']['instance-id']:}
```

So, it is impossible call to an unexisting fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You would use the stdlib function `has_key`, e.g.

```
include stdlib
if has_key($facts['ec2_metadata'], 'instance-id') {
  notice("All OK")
}
```

Documentation is [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib).

Comment: Works fine. Thanks Alex.